# Python - List Filtering

Tags: python, list

Can someone explain to me why this code removes only one element from the list not each as I would expect?  
So I have a list, let's say it is: [1,2,'a','b']  
I want to remove each string from the list.

```
def filter_list(l):
    for i in l:
        if type(i) == str:
           l.remove(i)

filter_list([1,2,'a','b'])
```

So after this I receive = [1,2,'b'] which is confusing.

Comment: Because you're modifying the list you're iterating over

Comment: So how am I supposed to remove each string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out:

```
l = [1,2,'a','b']
print([item for item in l if isinstance(item, int)])
```

I suggest you use isinstance built-in function instead of type. And also it is better to check is an integer in case of your list has an item that different from string or integer.

If you want to remove it, you can simply assign the new list on the old one.

```
l = [1,2,'a','b']
l = [item for item in l if isinstance(item, int)]
print(l)
```

Why you cannot over loop:
Let me explain.

```
def filter_list(l):
    for index, i in enumerate(l):
        if type(i) == str:
           l.remove(i)
    return l
filter_list([1,2,'a','b'])
```

1st iteration the index of for loop is 0:
`i` becomes 1, and no need to remove it.

2nd iteration the index of for loop is 1:
`i` becomes 2, and no need to remove it.

3rd iteration the index of for loop is 2:
`i` becomes `'a'`, and need to remove it.

At this point, we simply removed the `'a'`. The length of the list changed.
It decreased by 1. The new list became `[1, 2, 'b']` because we removed `'a'`.

4th iteration the index of for loop is 3:
Since we removed the variable in the previous iteration, the list no longer has the index of 3. The loop will raise StopIteration error(IndexError), and breaks.

That is why we cannot do this properly.

Comment: Still, why cant I loop over this?

Comment: I have tried to explain why :)

Answer (score -1):

Lambda Function:

```
[*filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, int), l)]
```

Data:

```
l = [1,2,'a','b']
```

Comment: Why downvoted ? I don't see this solution or this question duplicated anywhere (in its exact form).